# How to break a giant table into multiple smaller tables

Tags: sql, python-3.x, netezza

I have a table that looks like the one below. The table has two columns, Rank and Weight, and Rank is listed in descending order. The actual table has ~300,000 rows.

```
+------+--------+
| Rank | Weight |
+------+--------+
|    1 | 0.056  |
|    2 | 0.239  |
|    3 | 0.094  |
|    4 | 0.205  |
|    5 | 0.234  |
|    6 | 0.277  |
|    7 | 0.062  |
|    8 | 0.223  |
|    9 | 0.211  |
|   10 | 0.258  |
+------+--------+
```

I have suddenly found myself in the situation of needing turn the table into a printable format with smaller tables that has to look similar to something like below.

```
+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
| Rank | Weight | Rank | Weight | Rank | Weight |
+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
|    1 | 0.056  |   11 | 0.105  |   21 | 0.176  |
|    2 | 0.239  |   12 | 0.168  |   22 | 0.075  |
|    3 | 0.094  |   13 | 0.265  |   23 | 0.136  |
|    4 | 0.205  |   14 | 0.254  |   24 | 0.284  |
|    5 | 0.234  |   15 | 0.239  |   25 | 0.217  |
|    6 | 0.277  |   16 | 0.147  |   26 | 0.281  |
|    7 | 0.062  |   17 | 0.118  |   27 | 0.121  |
|    8 | 0.223  |   18 | 0.232  |   28 | 0.263  |
|    9 | 0.211  |   19 | 0.073  |   29 | 0.097  |
|   10 | 0.258  |   20 | 0.232  |   30 | 0.148  |
+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+

+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
| Rank | Weight | Rank | Weight | Rank | Weight |
+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
|   31 | 0.278  |   41 | 0.147  |   51 | 0.22   |
|   32 | 0.221  |   42 | 0.293  |   52 | 0.121  |
|   33 | 0.254  |   43 | 0.169  |   53 | 0.219  |
|   34 | 0.253  |   44 | 0.119  |   54 | 0.218  |
|   35 | 0.108  |   45 | 0.28   |   55 | 0.218  |
|   36 | 0.082  |   46 | 0.128  |   56 | 0.144  |
|   37 | 0.289  |   47 | 0.152  |   57 | 0.213  |
|   38 | 0.073  |   48 | 0.144  |   58 | 0.165  |
|   39 | 0.138  |   49 | 0.228  |   59 | 0.207  |
|   40 | 0.111  |   50 | 0.174  |   60 | 0.074  |
+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a display issue and not a SQL one really.  You could write the result set to an array and simply access array for row[i] row[i+10], row [i+20] iterate 10 times break out close out of table start a new table and now i becomes i+20. so your next record is 31..

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this?

Yes there is. Python comes with formatting built in, see [the docs on python formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). You will likely need to come up with an algorithm for grouping ranks into tables.

P.S I'm not inclined to share much more as this seems like a homework problem. What have you done already? What has or has not worked?

Comment: This is actually work related. The table is the end results of a SQL query. We never really needed to print this table in its entirety before, so this is a new problem for us.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Do you need a SQL solution that returns results printed in this format? Or are you open to getting back the 300k rows and crunching them with python to make it more readable?